# How can I find min or max valued item index for one of struct array items with Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Lets say we have a struct and an array made of that struct.

```
struct MyStruct {
  item1: Int = 0
  item2: Int = 0
}


var myStruct: [MyStruct] = []
```

Consider that we filled myStruct array with some data with append like that.

```
myStruct.append(MyStruct(item1: 12, item2:123) )
```

Think that we have 10 value in myStruct array like  [ (item1: 12, item2: 123),... ,() ]

And we want to find index number of myStruct according to item1 max value.

I can do it with a loop but there might be a ready way maybe which I can not find.

This is my in 1 min found solution;

```
func findMaxIndexForItem1() -> Int {
  var maxIndex = 0
  var max = 0
  for k in 0..<myStruct.count {
      if myStruct[k].item1 > max {
          max = myStruct[k].item1
          index = k    
       }
  }
   
    return max
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`max(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2906531-max) and pass in a closure that returns whether one index of the array is "smaller" than another. The method will use this to determine the index that is not smaller than any other index.

```
let index = myStruct.indices.max(by: 
    { myStruct[$0].item1 < myStruct[$1].item1 }
)
```

Comment: Well that was what I think could be existed but I dont know why but this things with $ are always irritating me.

Comment: @Hope I suggest you read the [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) section of the swift guide if you are confused about that.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by making `MyStruct` conform to `Comparable` protocol.
To conform to `Comparable` you need to specify what makes two instances of of your instance < or == each to each.

Once you have define that, you get a lot of functionality for free. For eg: You can check if two instances are equal (by your definition), find the max, min etc.

```
struct MyStruct : Comparable {
  var item1: Int = 0
  var item2: Int = 0

    static func < (lhs : MyStruct, rhs : MyStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.item1 < rhs.item1
    }

    static func == (lhs : MyStruct, rhs : MyStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.item1 == rhs.item1
    }

}


let arr = [MyStruct(item1: 20, item2: 0), MyStruct(item1: 10, item2: 0), MyStruct(item1: 5, item2: 0)]
let maxObj = arr.max()
maxObj?.item1
```

Comment: You are defining what == and < is for this struct based on only one use case,  how can you draw this conclusion? What says == should always be defined this way?

Comment: Well the question says "And we want to find index number of myStruct according to item1 max value."  and I also state *You can check if two instances are equal (by your definition)*

Comment: It's not so much what the question says as it is that you change the definition and behaviour of `MyStruct` with this solution.